# Use gtest to catch segfaults

Tags: ros, catkin, rostest, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure how to get catkin to catch segfaults during testing. I've setup a ROS gtest using the following line in my CMakeLists:

```
if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  catkin_add_gtest(moveit_bolt_test test/moveit_bolt_test.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(moveit_bolt_test ${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
endif()
```

I run the test using `catkin run_tests --no-deps --this -iv`

When the test segfaults, however, there is not reporting of test failures:

```
[bolt_moveit:make] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[bolt_moveit:make] Cannot find results, writing failure results to '/home/dave/ros/current/ws_swri/build_release/bolt_moveit/test_results/bolt_moveit/MISSING-gtest-moveit_bolt_test.xml'
[bolt_moveit:make] -- run_tests.py: verify result "/home/dave/ros/current/ws_swri/build_release/bolt_moveit/test_results/bolt_moveit/gtest-moveit_bolt_test.xml"
```

How do I get gtest to report a failure instead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244753/use-gtest-to-catch-segfaults/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2016-09-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the test segfaulted it didn't write the expected result file. Therefore the script wrapping the test invocation generated `MISSING-gtest-moveit_bolt_test.xml` which should contain a failed test. How do you expect the test failure to be reported? Did you run `catkin_test_results` afterwards?

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2016-09-29**:
I'm not running this in a CI currently, so didn't use catkin_test_results. I guess that is the tool that I'm missing, thanks.